# nattable multiple row selection

Tags: java, nebula, selectionmodel, nattable

I am using NatTable and I want to select some rows in my table. Additional I want to select some other rows after this (CTRL + left mouse-click).

There is no problem with the first selection, but when I try to select some additional rows, my first selection got lost. This happens only if I do my second selection in dragmode. When I select every additional row by single clicking everything works fine.

I used the RowSelectionModel with the DefaultRowSelectionLayerConfiguration:

```
    selectionLayer.setSelectionModel(new RowSelectionModel<Entry>(selectionLayer, bodyDataProvider, new IRowIdAccessor<Entry>() {

        @Override
        public Serializable getRowId(Entry rowObject) {
            return rowObject.getStartLine();

        }
    }));
    selectionLayer.addConfiguration(new DefaultRowSelectionLayerConfiguration());
```

Maybe I just did a silly mistake and you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an issue in the NatTable code. I created a ticket for this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494392

Comment: Thanks for the fast action. I saw on the ticket that the bug is fixed now. When is this bugfix available in the nattable software?

Comment: I proposed a fix ... it needs to be reviewed. If everything is fine I will include this bugfix in the 1.4 release next week. In the meanwhile you should be able to create a locally fixed version and register it with the SelectionLayer instance.

Comment: Alright, I will do this and hopefully the fix proposal is in the next release. Thanks again for your help.